# How can I get a Modal rather than a pop up when using http to access my facebook iframe page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, https

When using fb.UI  https hosted iframe pages give a proper modal dialog, but the same page via http gives a popup

here is my code, largely from the facebook dialogs help page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>oh, hello.</p>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "myappid", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'http://www.facebook.com/testapp/app_myappid/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',

        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }



    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So when i go to the page via https://www.facebook.com/testapp/app_myappid  I get a proper modal dialog but http://www.facebook.com/testapp/app_myappid  gives a horrid pop up.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried adding the *display* parameter, like so:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://www.facebook.com/testapp/app_myappid/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
    display: 'iframe'
};

...

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

---

## Edit

As it says in the same document I posted:

> If you specify iframe, you must have a valid access_token.

Looking at your code, you did seem to skip the authentication process. You see, you can't just call *FB.init* and then start using the api, you need to ask the SDK to authenticate the user.

There are some ways to do so, you should check the [Client-Side Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/) document for more info.
Here's your modified code, I added the use of the [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method of the SDK, and it states that:

> Calling FB.login results in the JS SDK attempting to open a popup
>   window. As such, this method should only be called after a user click
>   event, otherwise the popup window will be blocked by most browsers.

So you might need to authorize this popup for it to work, you should in reality use another approach (as discussed in that client side auth doc) or just call this method after a user clicked something.
This is just to give you a nudge to the right direction:

```
function callback(response) {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
}

function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'http://www.facebook.com/testapp/app_myappid/',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
    };

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}

FB.init({
    appId: "myappid", 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true
});

FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        postToFeed();
    }
    else {
        alert("user NOT logged in");
    }
});
```

---

## 2nd Edit

Since it's a canvas app, and you would like to avoid the login popup, there's another solution.

If you get that error message it means that you're (probably) missing a client side auth, you can pass along the access token you have from the server side and use it in the client, or you can do something like this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: "myappid", 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === "connected") {
            postToFeed();
        }
        else {
            console.log("not logged in to facebook or hasn't authorized the app");
        }
    };
};

function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'http://www.facebook.com/testapp/app_myappid/',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
    };

    function callback(response) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

This won't open a popup or anything of that sort, and will just check the user login status.
You can read more about the [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) method.

Also, I recommend using the [Channel File](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) parameter when initializing the js sdk. It should not make any difference in this case, but it's safer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that fires the modal, but with an error - "Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key"  which i didn't get with the popup.  How do i set the session key?

Comment: Check out the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for persisting with this, but FB.login isn't fixing it in my case.  This is an iframe in a facebook page.  The users are logged into facebook, have liked the app to get this far, and we want to show the share dialog at the end. https://www.facebook.com/appid works fine , http://www.facebook.com/appid  does not.  we get the error 102 error. "Session key invalid or no longer valid".  Displaying a login at this point wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I edited my answer, I don't understand the urls you posted, *www.facebook.com/appid* is not a canvas url, maybe you meant **apps**.facebook.com/appid?